# Upload image in angular5

Tags: file-upload, angular5

I had this piece of code that worked fine in angular4

```
 public SetHeaders(page?: number, itemsPerPage?: number, image?: boolean) {

    let tokenValue = "Bearer " + this._OidcSecurityService.getToken();
    if (!image) {
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': tokenValue,
            'Pagination': page + "," + itemsPerPage
        });
    } else if (image) {
        //this.headers.delete('Content-Type');
        //this.headers.delete('Accept');
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
           'Authorization': tokenValue
        });
    }

}
```

I moved up to angular 5 and now the following portion does not work anymore

```
else if (image) {
        //this.headers.delete('Content-Type');
        //this.headers.delete('Accept');
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
           'Authorization': tokenValue
        });
    }
```

The following method retrieves the user input and creates the formdata object which is the passed on the dataservice

```
AdmitStudent() {
    this.GetStudentPicture();
    this.url = this.admissionResourceApiUrl + "AdmitStudent";
    this._dataService.SetHeaders(0, 0, true);

    let input = new FormData();
    input.append("stdpic", this.admissionModel.Picture);
    this._dataService.AddRecord(this.url, this.admissionModel)
        .subscribe((resp => {
            this.response = resp.result;
            if (this.response == "OK") {
                this.admissionModel = new StudentViewModel();
                this.GetAdmissions(this.clsGrp.ProgrammeID, this.vacancyInfo.Term.TermID, this.clsGrp.StageID);
            }
        }))
}
```

This where I retrieve the picture from the user

```
private GetStudentPicture() {
    let stdpicElement = this.stdpic.nativeElement;
    if (stdpicElement.files && stdpicElement.files[0]) {
        this.admissionModel.Picture = stdpicElement.files[0];
    }
}
```

Below is the method in the dataservice that does sends the post request

```
public AddRecord<T>(url: string, model: Object) {
    return this._http.post<T>(url, model, { headers: this.headers, observe: 'response' })
        .map(res => {
            this.dataModel.result = res.statusText;
            return this.dataModel;
        },this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Incorrect Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Can you show the code for your upload service? (where you do your post/put)

Comment: I think I might just have seen what I did wrong.  let me fix that and get back to you

Comment: FormData is never used?

Comment: Exactly David, I cant believe I went through all the trouble to create it and yet never used it and had to go troubling the whole world, Thanks MAN!!